# Specific WMS request for printing

Tags: geoserver, wms, printing, dpi

I wish to use a special wms request for printing only.
full request looks like:
`/geoserver/test_osm/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=osm%3Atest_layerset&format_options=dpi:300&TILED=false&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=724&HEIGHT=363&BBOX=3928863.2538580596%2C7362108.816315036%2C4371586.5216858005%2C7584081.946455188` , where `WIDTH` & `HEIGHT` and `BBOX` parametres are worked additionally of size of openlayers's map dom object..

but I have a problem: size of label,lines parts of layerset and a size of a polygon lines are not grow linear:
300 dpi:
[image]

same with 150 dpi:
[image]

How to fix it and what a reason?
May be I have to use more efficiently approach for printing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual for `format_options`](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#format-options) clearly states that you need to adjust the size of your image to match an increase in dpi. It looks like you haven't done this so you end up with a "zoomed in" version of the map.

> In general, the image size should be increased by a factor equal to targetDPI/90, with the target dpi set in the format options. For example, to print a 100x100 image at 300 DPI request a 333x333 image with the DPI value set to 300: &width=333&height=333&format_options=dpi:300